# "Do I Try" not as a question

Tags: questions, emphasis

Recently I was speaking to a friend (also an ELL)  and he told me that the verse "And I try, oh my God, do I try", from ["What's Up - 4 Non Blondes"](http://www.metrolyrics.com/whats-up-lyrics-4-non-blondes.html) has the "**do I try**" actually as an emphasis (meaning that the person **REALLY TRIES**) rather than a [rhetoric] question.

The other friend says, that even without the question mark, this is definitely a question.

Is it possible to say : "Oh, Do I Work!" and be a valid English construction emphasizing how much I work?!

Any references?

Comment: In the modern AmE idiom, we would insert the adverb _ever_: _"Oh, do I ever work!"_ (_Ever_ here has the sense _"Constantly, incessantly, perpetually; with continual recurrence.."_ - OED.) However, it's an exclamation, I think, and not an interrogative.

Comment: Your first friend is right: it's used there for emphasis, not to form a question.

Comment: I think you'll find it's both. It's emphatic *because*it's a question asked when the audience the answer, and so could only respond by explaining how (much) the speaker tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first friend is correct in this case. Here's another example sentence of this kind of usage:

> Person 1: Do you work hard?
>
> Person 2: Oh boy do I!

By switching do and I person 2 is putting emphasis on how hard they work.